# Targeting Windows XP which Windows SDK to use? (7.0a or 7.1)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I'll targeting Windows XP+ in a new project and I'll be using Visual Studio 2010 for the task. Looking at things I saw that Visual Studio ships with the Windows SDK 7.0a, but there is a newer one that allows to target Windows XP too, v7.1.

That comes as a separate product that I have to install in a [special manner](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2011/04/01/visual-c-2010-sp1-compiler-update-for-the-windows-sdk-7-1.aspx) apparently, but I wonder if that's really necessary. I mean, is there any difference between 7.0a and 7.1 (e.g. compilers, headers or libraries available, ...)? Or can Visual Studio 2010 be used without Windows SDK 7.1 and get the same results?

Comment: Generally the way it works is that newer Windows SDK releases have new functionality that was added in newer Windows releases, for instance a new function or interface.  For Windows XP it is not going to matter, but it you want to dynamically access new functionality (e.g. stuff added in Windows 7 or 8) then you will want the newest SDK for its definitions of enums, structs, function typedefs, interfaces, etc.

Comment: 7.1 was the final SDK release for Windows 7.  It covers the bits that were added in SP1.  Very unlikely you care when you target XP as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answers, I think I'll stay with v7.0a; I don't think I'll be using anything newly added.